# Create an Array with random numbers

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, random, program-entry-point

How I do create an array of size 256 with sorted random numbers in the main method?
I want to create an array that randomly generates numbers between 1-256, the size would be 256 as well which means it would have 256 numbers in the array and they're sorted.
My code only returns me zero?

```
public class Array {
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        double[] randomarray = new double[256];
        for(int i = 0; i<randomarray.length;i++)
            randomarray[i] =  Math.random();
        
        for (int i = 0; i<randomarray.length;i++)
            System.out.println(randomarray[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! What do you think `(int) Math.random()` gives you?

Comment: Try `int[] randomarray = new Random().ints(256, 1, 256 + 1).toArray();`

Comment: random numbers?

Comment: I don't know how you get zeros. Math.random() gives you pseudo-random numbers from 0 to 1 so you can just multiply it by your range e.g. 256.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Streams

As @saka1029 [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62667580/create-an-array-with-random-numbers#comment110823248_62667580), the easiest (less code) way is by creating a [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html), a stream of `int` values, produced by a call to [`Random.ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Random.html#ints()).

```
int[] sortedRandoms = 
    new Random()              // Access a random-number generator.
    .ints(256, 1, 256 + 1)    // Generate a stream of int values, an `IntStream` object.
    .sorted()                 // Sort those generated `int` values.
    .toArray();               // Return the generated `int` values in an array.
```

here I added sorting as well.

Comment: Good Answer. As a habit, I would use [`ThreadLocalRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) rather than `Random`.

Answer (score 2):

`Math.random()` returns a `double` between 0.0 and 1.0, and casting to an `int` floors `double`s, so you're setting all of your array members to 0. You'll need to multiply `Math.random()` by your desired max value before you cast it to `int`.

Comment: @Jack: Read the last sentence of the answer. Don't post significant code in comments please.